# rsync with remote fat32

Tags: rsync, fat32

I've a script that syncs files between my server to my mobile via sshpass:

```
sshpass -p password rsync -vrz source1 source2 -e ssh user@ip:dest
```

using

```
-vrz
```

rsync everytime checks all files to mobile,

using

```
-vrz --update --modify-window=1
```

rsync doesn't update newer files from server to mobile

how are the correct options to use rsync with fat32?

Comment: Have you tried with --size-only?

Comment: You may be running into trouble with FAT32's low-precision timestamps, in which case adding `--modify-window=2` might help. See [this previous answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/54949/how-can-i-use-rsync-with-a-fat-file-system/144475#144475) and its comments.